# How to integrate DataTable Editor as Lib into CI3?

Tags: datatable, codeigniter-3

I have CI3 project, I have worked on Datatables Editor out of CI3 and actually I need to integrate to the application. after googling, I dont get any thing that can help doing so. the link I found is no longer accessible http://ci.dubbel16.nl/index.php/2015/12/22/codeigniter-with-datatables-and-editor/.

can you help to share any information that can help please ?

Thanks,

I have developped it out of CI3 and currently I need to put run on CI3.

Comment: That link is still accessible via the internet archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20221128053339/https://ci.dubbel16.nl/index.php/2015/12/22/codeigniter-with-datatables-and-editor/